# How to parse Multipart Form in NodeJs/ExpressJs having files nested in form data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, multipartform-data

I am sending a multipart form request to my NodeJs/ExpressJs application server with dynamic file fields in the Multipart form which are nested inside an object. For example:

```
multipartFormData = {
   title: 'Virtual Assistant',
   education: [
      {
         description: 'VA Certification from XYZ University'
      }
   ],
   portfolio: [
      { 
        title: 'Microsoft Power BI',
        certificate: File
      },
      { 
        title: 'Google Certified VA',
        certificate: File
      }
   ]
}
```

Here certification in the portfolio is a File and user can add more portfolio items to it. How can I parse this Multipart form at the server using NodeJs and ExpressJs so that I can get access to the certificate field in the portfolio? After which I can save it to the server and add the URL for it instead of file in the Database.

I have tried using multiparty dependency but it returns Files as an empty object {} and fields with the portfolio field as an array of string "[object Object]" which is a literal string.

multer as well doesn't support parsing forms in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipart Form Data with nested object structure needs to be handled specially. After some tries, I was able to accomplish what I needed with the help of two Libraries. One at the frontend named "object-to-formdata" which can be installed as **npm i object-to-formdata**

When this object is sent to the Backend as the request payload it can be parsed by the NodeJs/ExpressJs server using this dependency **multiparty** which can be installed using **npm i multiparty** this will parse JSON data separately and Files separately with a fieldName field in the parsed files so that you can identify where to hook the File after necessary action is taken.

This helped me to save my multipart form data with a single request including JSON data as well as Files in the nested objects.

Comment: can you please share an example or sample?

Answer (score 0):

```
import express from 'express';
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/',multipartMiddleware,controller.create);


module.exports = router;



try this in route file and add middleware in post method
npm using ('connect-multiparty')
while uploading file,set content type = formType...
```

Comment: Let me try this. Plus can you verify is you last line incomplete: while uploading file,set content type = formType...
?

Comment: This method doesn't work either. Files are still coming as {} empty object and the JSON data which is there along with the form is coming as a string of '[object Object]'